# Ansible - Power of 2 loop on a variable

Tags: loops, variables, math, prompt, ansible

I need:

```
  vars_prompt:
    - name: loopvar
      prompt: Enter the loop variable
      private: False
      default: 16
- hosts: epcs
  serial:1


  gather_facts: no
  tasks:

    - name: Do some mathematics divide multiply
      #insert logic here
      register: my_content  # save logic in register
      with_sequence: count={{loopvar}}  #I need a loop sequence here
      when: inventory_hostname == "vm1"
      ignore_errors: yes
```

A simple loop in c++ would be sth like:

```
int x=0;
for (int i=1; i<loopvar; i+=pow(2,x)) //pow is a math function with pow(2,x)= 2^x                                                                
{
    cout<<hi;
    x++;
}
```

One more thing, how can I store the results of each iteration in a register, so that I have it available,  when the playbook runs serially the 2nd, 3rd or 4th time etc.

Update:
Jinja2 allows the following:
Raise the left operand to the power of the right operand.

```
 {{ 2**3 }} would return 8.
```

Now keeping this new information in mind, can we do a power of 2 loop?

Answer (score 1):

The type of loop you want is not going to be possible in Ansible. The tool is limited to looping over a list, dictionary, or a sequence but the counter cannot be modified.  See the [ansible docs on loops](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_loops.html#using-register-with-a-loop).

For something like this you may want to look into writing a [custom module](http://docs.ansible.com/developing_modules.html).

> One more thing, how can I store the results of each iteration in a register, so that I have it available, when the playbook runs serially the 2nd, 3rd or 4th time etc.

See the section in the Ansible docs [on how to use register in a loop](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_loops.html#using-register-with-a-loop). 
If you register a var named `my_content` you can access the individual results in `my_content.results`.

Comment: Ok thanks for the input. How do I do sth like my_content.results[1] etc?

Comment: That should work fine, the ansible debug module is helpful for dumping the value of a var if it helps.  `- debug var={{ my_content.results[1] }}` will show you the second result registered in the loop,

Comment: Raise the left operand to the power of the right operand. {{ 2**3 }} would return 8. What about jinja math like I just did

Comment: You can do that but I don't think what you are trying to accomplish, a sequence where the counter is modified is not possible. Anything more complicated than what is described in the docs for loops is going to be ugly and you will be fighting ansible to get it to work.